# Inject same instance at all places in Activity Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have an Activity with multiple fragments, each fragment has its own ViewModel. These ViewModels use a common repository which is injected to it. I want to inject the same instance of that repository at all places and the lifecycle of those repositories are scoped to the Activity. Can I achieve this using Hilt?

Comment: "and the lifecycle of those repositories are scoped to the Activity" -- that would be *very* unusual from an Android app architecture standpoint. If you have stuff that is scoped to the lifecycle of the activity, use an activity-scoped `ViewModel`. Repositories are designed to live beyond the scope of any particular screen.

Comment: I just want to explore if that is possible. there might be scenario where my object is getting accessed from multiple fragment VMs and stores certain data fetched from server. I dont want to fetch it again.  I simply want same instance of dataholder to be injected everywhere but scoped to activity instead of application.